# Exception error in function lists:foldl/3 (lists.erl, line 1263)

Tags: erlang

## Question

Why when I run a function it works but when I pass it to `lists:foldl` it does not work?

---

## Detailed explanation

When I run a specific function in the terminal, it returns the expected result. But if I pass this function to lists:foldl, it throws an exception.

The problematic function is `separate_socks/2`.

When I run it directly, it returns:

```
> sock_merchant:separate_socks(1, #{1 => [1]}).
#{1 => [1,1]}

> sock_merchant:separate_socks(1, #{}).        
#{1 => [1]}
```

But when I run the `test/0`, it returns:

```
> sock_merchant:test().                        
** exception error: bad function separate_socks
     in function  lists:foldl/3 (lists.erl, line 1263)
```

My `sock_merchant.erl` file has the following content:

```
% John works at a clothing store. He has a large pile of socks that he must pair
% by color for sale. Given an array of integers representing the color of each
% sock, determine how many pairs of socks with matching colors there are.

% For example, there are `n = 7` socks with colors `ar = [1,2,1,2,1,3,2]`. There
% is one pair of color 1 and one of color 2. There are three odd socks left, one
% of each color. The number of pairs is 2.

-module(sock_merchant).

-export([count_number_of_pair_of_sockets/2,
         filter_socks/2,
         separate_socks/2,
         sock_merchant/2,
         test/0,
         test_sock_merchant/0]).

%% Next: number
%% Acc: map
separate_socks(Next, Acc) ->
    KeyExists = maps:is_key(Next, Acc),

    case KeyExists of
        true ->
            CurrentKeyList = maps:get(Next, Acc),
            maps:update(Next, [Next | CurrentKeyList], Acc);
        false -> maps:put(Next, [Next], Acc)
    end.

%% Value: number
filter_socks(_, Value) ->
    if Value div 2 >= 1 -> true;
       true -> false
    end.

%% Next: {key, [number]}
%% Acc: number
count_number_of_pair_of_sockets({_, Arr}, Acc) ->
    Acc + length(Arr) div 2.

%% N: number
%% Ar: [number]
sock_merchant(_, Ar) ->
    % SocksSeparatedList = #{1: [1,1], 2: [2], ...}
    SocksSeparatedList = lists:foldl(separate_socks,
                                     #{},
                                     Ar),
    SocksWithPairs = maps:filter(filter_socks,
                                 SocksSeparatedList),
    ListOfSocksWithPairs = maps:to_list(SocksWithPairs),
    lists:foldl(count_number_of_pair_of_sockets,
                0,
                ListOfSocksWithPairs).

test_sock_merchant() ->
    3 = sock_merchant(9,
                      [10, 20, 20, 10, 10, 30, 50, 10, 20]),
    pass.

test() -> pass = test_sock_merchant().
```

I'm solving this problem from HackerRank https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/sock-merchant/problem?h_l=interview&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=interview-preparation-kit&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=warmup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term `separate_socks` is, by itself, an atom. This means when you call `lists:foldl/3` passing `separate_socks` as the first argument, you're just passing an atom, not a function as `lists:foldl/3` requires:

```
SocksSeparatedList = lists:foldl(separate_socks,
                                 #{},
                                 Ar),
```

To instead pass the function `separate_socks`, pass it as a function term:

```
SocksSeparatedList = lists:foldl(fun separate_socks/2,
                                 #{},
                                 Ar),
```

The `fun` keyword indicates a function, and the trailing `/2` is the function arity (its number of arguments).

Comment: Many thanks for the quick, precise, and complete answer!

Comment: You're welcome. Once you fix this and the other two cases of it in your code, you'll also find that the arguments to `filter_socks/2` need to be swapped, and then your test will pass.

Comment: Actually the arguments were right, but the `if` condition was wrong. This is the correct way `if length(Value) div 2 >= 1 -> true;`